# How do I get rid of these dark rectangles on the screen in Bioshock Infinite

Tags: pc, bioshock-infinite

I've already asked other people and looked all over and I can't find anyone else having this problem. And I don't have this problem on any other games.

I already tried verifying the games cache (although I knew that wouldn't work). I think it's caused by ShadowPlay because the squares are where the ShadowPlay status indicator and webcam overlays go.

However, disabling ShadowPlay doesn't fix it and neither does disabling the overlays inside ShadowPlay.

Here is a picture of the problem:
[image]

If I alt-tab and then go back in, they're gone for a second and then they show back up again.

They stay there the whole time and never move or flicker how do I get rid of them??

I know this isn't a question about the game and doesn't really belong here but I had no idea where else to ask that I might receive an answer.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph: on the contrary, we definitely support questions about this kind of stuff happening in games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel stupid. Restarting my computer fixed the issue. (I never restart my computer)

Comment: If a restart fixed it and it hasn't come back since, it could have been a simple matter of drivers that were waiting for a reboot to complete an update. Those should be the first thing you check when you're having weird graphical problems simply because they're usually the easiest fix.

Comment: Yeah I just never restart my computer. I run servers from my computer so I might restart my computer like once every 3 months.

Comment: You really should accept this answer, it keeps popping up to the front page as a question with no accepted answer.

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and then back on again?"